# net/http Transport Exceeding MaxConnsPerHost

Tags: go

I have a simple program below which is a simple HTTP client and server. I'm testing  if `MaxConnsPerHost` in `http.Transport` introduced in **Go 1.11** is working as advertised. However, when I run the code more than 10-30 minutes, the ESTABLISHED connections slowly exceeds the set `MaxConnsPerHost`. Am I doing something wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // Server
    //
    go func() {

        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", http.HandlerFunc(
            func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                w.Write([]byte("hi"))
            },
        )); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    }()

    // Client settings
    //
    c := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
                DualStack: true,
            }).DialContext,
            MaxIdleConns:          100,
            IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
            ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
            MaxConnsPerHost:       50,
        },
    }

    // Worker loop
    //
    threads := 500
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {

        go func() {

            for {

                req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8081", nil)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

                res, err := c.Do(req)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

                if _, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body); err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

                res.Body.Close()
            }

        }()
    }

    var done chan bool
    <-done
    log.Println("Done")

}
```

After running this for a long time, the ESTABLISHED connections reported by `netstat` is already exceeding 50.

P.S. We have an in issue in one of our services which horribly leaks ESTABLISHED connections even though we are properly closing the response's Body. It is currently built using **Go 1.10** and I was hoping **Go 1.11** `MaxConnsPerHost` would be a solution but it seems to also crack under heavy load.

Comment: Try disabling HTTP2. Per [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport), "For HTTP/2, this currently only controls the number of new connections being created at a time, instead of the total number." Also review your code; you have some nonsensical settings here, such as `MaxIdleConns` greater than `MaxConns`. It would also be useful to know how long "a long time" is, and by how much it is exceeding 50 connections (e.g. having 51 open connections could just be a delay between Go closing a connection  and the OS closing the socket).

Comment: 30 minutes to be sure, connections go up to 70+. If they are already closed, then `netstat` would not report them as ESTABLISHED. Also, I've already tried setting both the `MaxIdleConns` and `MaxConnsPerHost` to 50 to no avail. Anyway, I'll try disabling HTTP2 and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: If they are closed *by the OS*, netstat would not report them as ESTABLISHED. All Go can do is make a syscall to close the connection, at which point it considers it closed and frees up an available connection per MaxConns. That doesn't mean the OS has actually closed the socket; it just means that it should, get closed. Typically there is no appreciable delay, but with 500 threads opening and closing connections as fast as the CPU will let them, I wouldn't be that surprised to detect a discrepancy.

Comment: I'm wondering why the supposedly 50 initial connections are not totally reused since this is a very busy client. At 500 threads, those 50 connections won't have enough idle time to be sent back to the idle pool. We actually have an issue in one of our systems where we set the `MaxIdleConns` and after five days netstat is reporting 1000+ established connections. We seem to experience the same issue as this: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/9hi208/nethttp_client_high_number_of_established/

Comment: See https://play.golang.org/p/f3MO2PVlKOx where DialContext is wrapped with a function that counts the number of calls.  DialContext is called 50 times as expected with Go 1.16.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong?

It appears this bug has been resolved in more recent go versions, I can not reproduce this with:

```
$ go version 
go version go1.17.1 linux/amd64
```

monitoring:

```
watch -n 3 'ss  -tn | grep :8081 | sort -k 3,3n | tee >(wc -l) | tail ;
            ps -eo pid,etime,cmd | grep "leaky[-]server"'
```

running the server:

```
go run leaky-server.go
```

sample output after 2.5 hours:

```
Every 3.0s: ss  -tn | grep :8081 | sor...  balmora: Sun Oct 31 12:38:52 2021

ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43814
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43818
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43822
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43824
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43830
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43834
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43836
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43838
ESTAB 0      118                 [::1]:8081               [::1]:43844
100
 536182    02:30:03 go run leaky-server.go
 536269    02:30:03 /tmp/go-build2453595122/b001/exe/leaky-server
```